# Do I have to reconnect the database?

Tags: java, database-connection

I am connecting my Java program to MS Access.

When I deploy the program and Access file on another machine, do I need to connect to the database again using Administrative Tools in that computer?

Comment: `"do I need to connect to database again"`?  When is the first time you are connecting to the database?

Comment: The simplest option would be to try... use a virtual machine if you don't have access to another computer (no pun intended)

Comment: First time connecting to my computer and second time to another computer @Tim

Comment: I need to use the database and program in another computer @ Stephen